# Как сделать интерфейс Органайзера

Tags: c#, интерфейс, visual-studio

В поисках средств разработки интерфейса для органайзера, примерно похожий на этот:
[image]

Приложение для Windows, можно хоть WPF, хоть WinForm

Answer (score 1):

Всё! Нашел то что надо [здесь](http://easylab.net.ua/net-elementyi-upravleniya/c-nestandartnyiy-kalendar)